# How to add margin top in second page after page break in snappy pdf laravel?

Tags: css, laravel, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-snappy

I have used `page-break-inside: avoid;` for page break, that work fine. But in second page there is no margin in top.
[image]

```
<div class="section-wrapper keep-together">
            <div class="section-title">
                <p class="title">{{ $section['certification']['title'] }}</p>
                <p class="line"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="content-row">
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>{!! $section['certification']['data']['details'] !!}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

.section-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  .section-title {
    .title {
      font-size: 2rem;
      font-weight: 700;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: $color-blue;
      padding: 0 80px;
    }
  }
        .desc {
          margin-bottom: 2rem;
          font-weight: 300;
          font-size: 1.5rem;
          text-align: left;
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Need some margin in second page. I am using laravel 5.7 and snappy pdf

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: What part of code needed ? html or css ?  Sorry if i ask something silly

Comment: You have to post the code so we can understand clearly to solve your problem

Comment: @Shunhra Sarker You have to post both HTML and CSS code.

Comment: .keep-together {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
for automatic page break i use this piece of code and add keep-togather class every section